# How to test UI Interaction and manipulation of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, unit-testing, uiviewcontroller, tdd, bdd

I'm new to BDD and I'm trying to figure out how I could write a test for pressing the back button in my app, or whether BDD requires me to write a test at all.

Here's a few example scenarios with functionality:

```
What:     tapBackButton
Scenario: formNotSaved
Result:   showAlertNotifiyingTheUser

What:     tapBackButton
Scenario: formIsSaved
Result:   goes1ScreenBack
```

I have no idea how to write unit tests for this! I have added the OCMock framework but it doesn't seem like you're allowed to change a uiviewcontroller's navigation controller since its read-only.

I really want to change my development process to write a failing test first and then code, but this makes it difficult.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: Ended up watching google tech talk series about clean code: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL693EFD059797C21E  which explains a lot about writing tests and ways that code is written which prevents you from writing tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of Apple development, but I can comment on standard TDD stuff and that should get you in the right direction - I hope :)

What I'd do for this is have your "Alert" code in a seperate class with an interface, say IAlerter (unless Apple framework already has an interface for "messageboxes/alerts" that you can leverage).

Inject the interface into the constructor of your UI class..   Then in the test, you mock out the IAlerter in the test.

so basically.. (in C#, Moq (mocking library) style, Pseudocode sorry ;))

```
//ARRANGE
var alerterMock = new Moq.Mock<IAlerter>();//fake the alerter - cuz you really don't want it to happen, you just want to do a "Verify" that it "was" called.

var ui = new UI(alerterMock.Object);

//ACT
ui.StartDataEntry();
ui.GoBack();

//ASSERT
alerterMock.Verify(a => a.ShowAlert(Moq.It.IsAny<string>()));//verify ShowAlert was called with any string - or at least do a lil ".Contains" to make sure it was calling code that shows the text you expect.
```

HTH :)